# Set up VS Code environment for MAUI .NET 8 - Android

Tags: android, sdk, maui, .net-8.0, build-dependencies

I am desperately trying to set everything up on VS Code for Mac in order to be able to build and release MAUI .NET 8 apps. I also have a MAUI .NET 7 which I actually develop and build on VS for Mac 2022, but I will soon need to migrate it to this new IDE.
When I perform the  `dotnet build -t:InstallAndroidDependencies -f:net8.0-android -p:AcceptAndroidSDKLicenses=True` suggested command, I get the following output:

```
MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `platforms;android-34` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-34"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `build-tools;34.0.0` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "build-tools;34.0.0"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `platform-tools` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "platform-tools"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `cmdline-tools;11.0` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;11.0"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]

Build succeeded.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `platforms;android-34` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-34"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `build-tools;34.0.0` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "build-tools;34.0.0"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `platform-tools` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "platform-tools"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Installer.Common.targets(12,3): warning : Dependency `cmdline-tools;11.0` should have been installed but could not be resolved. You can attempt to install it with: `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;11.0"` [/Users/michelewilliammanco/Projects/TestNET/TestNET.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android]
    4 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

The issue is that I can't properly resolve the wanted SDK. I tried several times to install all the packages mentioned in the warnings using the `sdkmanager` executable in `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/11.0/bin` but it would say that the executable has been compiled with a more recent version of Java. If I try to execute the same command from `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/7.0/bin` it seems to work, but then nothing changes and the tools should have been installed but could not resolved anyway.
I am stuck in this weird situation. Consider also that, VS for Mac 2022 doesn't give me the possibility to install new Android SDK anymore, since it will be soon dismissed.
I would, if possible, like to avoid installing Android Studio for this SDK stuff, rather preferring to go through by CLI.
Do you have any idea on what is it annoying the MSBuild?

Comment: does your android sdk have `platforms;android-34` and `build-tools;34.0.0` and stuff from the other warnings?

Comment: @FreakyAli how can I check that? In VS for Mac I can’t install it anymore because it is out of support. Am I missing any installation package? Consider that I forgot to mention I already installed Microsoft OpenJDK 11.

Comment: May be this is what you are missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77516577/vs-macupdating-to-net-8-all-of-my-maui-projects-display-error-netsdk1139-the/77518683#77518683

Comment: No I am sorry. This is not the case. .NET 8 Sdk is correctly installed, in fact if I open up a new project and build, it works and runs. Still I can’t resolve those references to specific tools for Android.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the issue by:

- installing `cmdline-tools;11.0` with `/Users/michelewilliammanco/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/7.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;11.0"`
- installing everything else from the same path and using `sdkmanager`.
  It's good to know that for everything to be updated, the right folder from which to execute sdkmanager is 7.0 and **not 11.0**.

At the end of the procedure, my VS Code says everything is installed, updated and ready for development.