Android SDK Build Tools 34 and 35 are not displayed in Visual Studio for Mac. How can I install them?
In Visual Studio for Mac-->Tools-->SDK Manager--Android-->Tools, the Android SDK Build Tools 34 and 35 are not displayed, only older versions are displayed. How can I install the Android SDK Build Tools 34 and 35 in Visual Studio for Mac?


try command /sdk/tools/bin$ ./sdkmanager "build-tools;34.0.2"

It's not working when I use this in the Visual Studio Terminal. Is there another way to install the Android SDK Build Tools and the newest Android Command-line Tools?

Not sure if the SDK manager in VS gets it's packages from Google or Microsoft. May be it is a mixture and you don't get new packages because Microsoft doesn't provide new versions as VS for Mac is EOL? In that case install plain Android SDK from Google (comes with Android Studio).

I have already installed Android Studio. Android Studio installs the SDK in a different directory than Visual Studio for Mac and I'm not sure if I can use the same SDK directory for Visual Studio for Mac and Android Studio. Can I use the same SDK directory in Visual Studio than in Android Studio?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789358/set-up-vs-code-environment-for-maui-net-8-android       I have installed the missing components like this and now the Android SDK works in Visual Studio Code but still not in Visual Studio for Mac: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/cmdline-tools/7.0/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;11.0"
